# Duplicate files in Gradle-built .war file

Tags: java, build, build-process, duplicates, gradle

I'm having a duplicate files issue with my Gradle build script.

My directory structure is the maven standard, plus some extra directories for various build configurations:

```
/src/main/java
/src/main/resources
/src/main/dev/resources
/src/main/prod/resources
```

The files from `/src/main/resources` and `/src/main/dev/resources` are apparently handled by both the `processResources` and the `war` task, and end up in the .war file twice. **How can I prevent that from happening without manually excluding each single file in the war configuration?**

My entire build.gradle is included below; note `buildEnvironment` is set to `dev` by default, but could also be `prod`.

```
apply plugin: "sonar"
apply plugin: "war"
apply plugin: "eclipse-wtp"

// ************************************************************************************************
// GENERAL CONFIGURATION
// ************************************************************************************************

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
group = "com.foo"
archivesBaseName = "security"
version = "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

// versions of various components where we need more than one and may want to update often
def springVersion = "3.1.1.RELEASE"
def tomcatVersion = "7.0.25"
def jasperVersion = "4.5.0"

// buildEnvironment is set in gradle.properties and can be overridden with -PbuildEnvironment=... on the command line
println "running in $buildEnvironment mode..."

// set classes output directory to WEB-INF/classes
eclipse.classpath.defaultOutputDir = new File(project.getWebAppDir().getAbsolutePath(), "/WEB-INF/classes")

// ************************************************************************************************
// SOURCE SETS
// ************************************************************************************************

sourceSets {
  // add the resources specific to the build environment
  main.resources.srcDirs += "src/main/$buildEnvironment/resources"
  // add source set for jasper reports
  jasperreports {
    srcDir = file(relativePath('src/main/jasperreports'))
    output.classesDir = file(relativePath('src/main/java/com/foo/bar/security/statistics'))
  }
}

// ************************************************************************************************
// PLUGINS
// ************************************************************************************************

buildscript {
  repositories {
    add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()) {
      name = 'GitHub'
      addArtifactPattern 'http://cloud.github.com/downloads/[organisation]/[module]/[module]-[revision].[ext]'
    }
  }

  dependencies { classpath 'bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:0.9' }
}

apply plugin: "tomcat"

// ************************************************************************************************
// PLUGIN CONFIGURATION
// ************************************************************************************************

// configure eclipse .project/.classpath generator
eclipse {
  project { natures 'com.springsource.sts.gradle.core.nature' }
  wtp { component { contextPath = "/security" } }
}

configurations {
  // make sure we don't get dependencies we don't want
  all*.exclude group: "net.sf.ehcache", module: "ehcache-terracotta"
  all*.exclude group: "bouncycastle", module: "bcmail-jdk14"
  all*.exclude group: "bouncycastle", module: "bcprov-jdk14"
  all*.exclude group: "bouncycastle", module: "bctsp-jdk14"

  // wtp needs a special invitation for some reason
  eclipseWtpComponent {
    exclude group: "net.sf.ehcache", module: "ehcache-terracotta"
  }

  jasperreports { transitive = true }
}

// maven repositories
repositories {
  maven { url "http://maven.springframework.org/milestone/" }
  mavenCentral()
}

// sonar configuration
sonar {
  server { url = "http://xxx" }
  database {
    url = "jdbc:mysql://xxx"
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    username = "xxx"
    password = "xxx"
  }
  project { key = "foo.bar:security" }
}

war {
  // set war output file name
  archiveName = "security.war"
  // make sure no duplicate processing of files takes place
  excludes += [
    "**/database.properties",
    "**/logback.xml",
    "**/rebel.xml",
    "**/upload.properties",
    "**/ValidationMessages.properties"
  ]
}

tomcatRun { contextPath = "/security" }

// ************************************************************************************************
// DEPENDENCIES
// ************************************************************************************************

dependencies {

  // exclusions for jasperreports, which tries to load old versions of stuff
  compile("net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:$jasperVersion") {
    exclude module: "jfreechart"
    exclude module: "jcommon"
  }

  // exclusions for ehcache, we don't want their enterprise cache
  compile("net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:2.5.1") {
    exclude group: "net.sf.ehcache", module: "ehcache-terracotta"
  }

  // compile and runtime dependencies
  compile   "org.springframework:spring-webmvc:$springVersion",
      "org.springframework:spring-orm:$springVersion",
      "org.springframework:spring-aspects:$springVersion",
      "org.springframework.mobile:spring-mobile-device:1.0.0.RC1",
      "org.jfree:jfreechart:1.0.14",
      "org.apache.tiles:tiles-jsp:2.2.2",
      "c3p0:c3p0-oracle-thin-extras:0.9.1.2",
      "org.mybatis:mybatis-spring:1.0.2",
      "org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.6.12",
      "org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.6.12",
      "org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.4",
      "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.0.0",
      "org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.6.4",
      "org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.6.4",
      "org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.6.4",
      "org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:4.2.0.Final",
      "com.google.guava:guava:11.0.1",
      "commons-dbutils:commons-dbutils:1.4",
      "commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.2.2",
      "commons-io:commons-io:2.1",
      "commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6",
      "org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:1.46",
      "org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.1.3",
      "jdom:jdom:1.1",
      "cglib:cglib:2.2.2",
      "org.jasypt:jasypt:1.9.0",
      "com.sun.mail:smtp:1.4.4",
      "com.sun.mail:mailapi:1.4.4",
      "xalan:xalan:2.7.1",
      "org.jdom:saxpath:1.0-FCS"

  runtime "javax.servlet:jstl:1.2"

  // for compiling jasper reports
  jasperreports "net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:$jasperVersion",
      "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:1.8.6"

}

// dependencies for each tomcat version, which are in different packages for 6.x and 7.x, sigh
println "adding dependencies for Tomcat $tomcatVersion"
if (tomcatVersion.startsWith("6")) {
  dependencies.add("providedCompile", "org.apache.tomcat:catalina:$tomcatVersion")
  dependencies.add("tomcat", "org.apache.tomcat:catalina:$tomcatVersion")
  dependencies.add("tomcat", "org.apache.tomcat:coyote:$tomcatVersion")
  dependencies.add("tomcat", "org.apache.tomcat:jasper:$tomcatVersion")
} else if (tomcatVersion.startsWith("7")) {
  dependencies.add("providedCompile", "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-catalina:$tomcatVersion")
  dependencies.add("tomcat", "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-catalina:$tomcatVersion")
  dependencies.add("tomcat", "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-coyote:$tomcatVersion")
  dependencies.add("tomcat", "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jasper:$tomcatVersion")
}

// ************************************************************************************************
// JASPER REPORTS
// ************************************************************************************************

task jasperReports(overwrite: true) << {
  ant {
    taskdef(name: 'jrc',
        classname: 'net.sf.jasperreports.ant.JRAntCompileTask',
        classpath: configurations.jasperreports.asPath)
    mkdir(dir:sourceSets.jasperreports.output.classesDir)
    jrc(srcdir: sourceSets.jasperreports.srcDir, destdir: sourceSets.jasperreports.output.classesDir) {
      include(name:'**/*.jrxml')
      classpath {
        pathElement(path: configurations.jasperreports.asPath)
      }
    }
  }
}

task cleanJasperReports(overwrite: true) << {
  ant.delete() {
    fileset(dir:sourceSets.jasperreports.output.classesDir, includes: "*.jasper")
  }
}

compileJava.dependsOn jasperReports
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not tested your configuration here, but I think it's because you are adding `main.resources.srcDirs += "src/main/$buildEnvironment/resources"` to sourceSets. By adding this you have now the following sourceSets if `buildEnvironment = 'dev'`:

- src/main/java
- src/main/resources
- src/main/dev/resources

This means if you have a resource called `myfile.txt` in both `src/main/resources` and `src/main/dev/resources` you would get the following files:

- WEB-INF/classes/myfile.txt
- WEB-INF/classes/dev/myfile.txt

To fix this you could just move your dev/prod resources outside of `src/main`, ex. like this:

- src/main/java
- src/main/resources
- src/dev/resources
- src/prod/resources

And use the following sourceSet instead:

```
main.resources.srcDirs += "src/$buildEnvironment/resources"
```

Then all dev/prod resources will override the resources in `src/main/resources`.

Comment: That's what I did and it worked fine. Sorry, I only saw this now, the e-mail must've gotten buried in the spam folder...